# How do I import my walk cycle to my setting on Blender?

Tags: animation, blender

I have made a walk cycle, and a snowy forest setting both on Blender, however I made them in different files.

How do I copy the walk cycle over to my setting? I tried to use append but I don't know if it works if you have an animation.

**Walk Cycle:**
http://prnt.sc/dj19sz
**Snowy Setting**
http://prntscr.com/dj1amr

Answer (score 2):

You can just append or link the file. Appending will add the file into the new file, while linking will put a link to the other file into the new file. With linking, you could add the walk cycle into multiple new files and then change them all at once by changing the linked file. Appending does not have that feature.